# getting control object with Graphics from class instance

Tags: vb.net, graphics

i dont have much experience with Graphics class in winforms. 
i am only in the sketching stage of it (also the code i have added).
my problem is that i am trying to create a panel: `clockPanel` with some graphics on it, no exception is thrown but the panel (as i can see in the UI) have no graphics on it. tryed to look for examples but i cant find mistakes or something i missed in my code. probably its an easy one for those of you that experienced with graphics.
thank you for your time an consideration.

**VB CODE:**
*adding 'clockpanel' panel to other pannel ('secondaryPannel') via instance to GoalsClock class*

```
Public Class ManagersTab
...
  Public Sub BuiledDashBoard()
...
  Dim p As GoalsClock = New GoalsClock(100, 100, 0.8)
        p.Create()
        p.clockPanel.Location = New Point(200, 100)
        secondaryPannel.Controls.Add(p.clockPanel)
...
  End Sub
...
End Class
```

**Create() method is the most relevant part:**

```
Class GoalsClock

    Private Gclock As Graphics
    Private clockWidth As Int16
    Private clockHeight As Int16
    Private xPos As Int16
    Private yPos As Int16

    Public clockPanel As Panel
    Private panelColor As Color

    Private PercentTextColor As Color
    ' rectangles to store squares
    Protected OuterRect As Rectangle
    Protected InnerRect As Rectangle
    Protected InnerStringBrush As Brush
    Protected InnerStringColor As Color
    Protected InnerStringFontSize As Byte

    ' inner square
    Private InnerSquarePen As Pen
    Private InnerSquarePen_Color As Color
    Private InnerSquarePen_Width As Byte
    ' outer square
    Private OuterSquarePen As Pen
    Private OuterSquarePen_Color As Color
    Private OuterSquarePen_Width As Byte

    Private _PercentOfGoals As Single ' to calculate the goals deg arc
    Public Property PercentOfGoals() As Single
        Get
            Return _PercentOfGoals * 100
        End Get
        Private Set(ByVal value As Single)
            If value <= 1.0F Then
                _PercentOfGoals = value
            Else
                value = 0
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Sub New(ByVal clockWidth As Int16, ByVal clockHeight As Int16, ByVal GoalsPercent As Single)
        Me.clockWidth = clockWidth
        Me.clockHeight = clockHeight
        PercentOfGoals = GoalsPercent


        ' values for test
        xPos = 0
        yPos = 0
        InnerStringFontSize = 12
        OuterSquarePen = New Pen(Color.Gray)
        InnerSquarePen = New Pen(Color.Cyan)
        OuterSquarePen_Width = 23
        InnerSquarePen_Width = 15
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' 
    '''  create graphics of the goals clock on clockPanel
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Sub Create()
        ' panel
        clockPanel = New Panel()
        clockPanel.Size = New Size(clockWidth, clockHeight)
        clockPanel.BackColor = Color.Beige
        Gclock = clockPanel.CreateGraphics()
        ' create outer rectangle
        OuterRect = New Rectangle(xPos, yPos, clockWidth, clockHeight)
        ' create inner rectangle
        Dim w, h, x, y As Integer
        getInnerRectSizeAndLocation(w, h, x, y)
        InnerRect = New Rectangle(x, y, w, h)
        ' draw goals string inside inner rect
        InnerStringBrush = Brushes.Cyan
        Gclock.DrawString(getPercentString(), New Font("ARIAL", InnerStringFontSize, FontStyle.Bold), InnerStringBrush, InnerRect)

        ' create outer square
        OuterSquarePen = New Pen(OuterSquarePen_Color, OuterSquarePen_Width)
        Gclock.DrawArc(OuterSquarePen, OuterRect, 1.0F, 360.0F)

        ' create inner square
        InnerSquarePen = New Pen(InnerSquarePen_Color, InnerSquarePen_Width)
        Dim sweepAngle As Short = getSweepAngleFromGoalsPercent()
        Gclock.DrawArc(InnerSquarePen, OuterRect, -90.0F, sweepAngle)

    End Sub

    Private Sub getInnerRectSizeAndLocation(ByRef w As Integer, ByRef h As Integer, ByRef x As Integer, ByRef y As Integer)
        ' values for test
        w = 40
        h = 40
        x = 64
        y = 65
    End Sub

    Private Function getPercentString() As String
        Return PercentOfGoals.ToString() & "%"
    End Function

    Private Function getSweepAngleFromGoalsPercent() As Single
        ' value for test
        Return 0.0F
    End Function


End Class
```

Comment: Remove that Gclock variable.  You should never store the graphic object.  It's meant to have a limited life time.  Never use the CreateGraphics method either.  Those graphics are temporary and will get easily erased if you minimize the form, etc.

Comment: @LarsTech : First thing already pointed out. :)

Comment: Another sailor lost in the CreateGraphics triangle.  As long as you are learning Winforms programming from scratch, *do* consider WPF first.  It is more compatible with the way you think.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @LarsTech.  Very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must subscribe to the panel's [**`Paint` event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint(v=vs.110).aspx) and perform all drawing there. The [**`AddHandler` statement**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx) is used to dynamically subscribe to events.

The `Graphics` class will not store any information about what you draw, so when your panel is redrawn everything you previously drew will be gone unless you draw it again. This is where the `Paint` event comes into play: it will be raised every time your panel is redrawn, passing an instance of a `Graphics` class in its `PaintEventArgs` so you can draw your stuff onto the panel again.

```
Public Sub Create()
    ' panel
    clockPanel = New Panel()
    clockPanel.Size = New Size(clockWidth, clockHeight)
    clockPanel.BackColor = Color.Beige

    ' subscribe to the panel's paint event
    AddHandler clockPanel.Paint, AddressOf clockPanel_Paint
End Sub

Private Sub clockPanel_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
    Dim Gclock As Graphics = e.Graphics 'Local variable only, as the Graphics object might change.
    ' create outer rectangle
    OuterRect = New Rectangle(xPos, yPos, clockWidth, clockHeight)
    ' create inner rectangle
    Dim w, h, x, y As Integer
    getInnerRectSizeAndLocation(w, h, x, y)
    InnerRect = New Rectangle(x, y, w, h)
    ' draw goals string inside inner rect
    InnerStringBrush = Brushes.Cyan
    Gclock.DrawString(getPercentString(), New Font("ARIAL", InnerStringFontSize, FontStyle.Bold), InnerStringBrush, InnerRect)

    ' create outer square
    OuterSquarePen = New Pen(OuterSquarePen_Color, OuterSquarePen_Width)
    Gclock.DrawArc(OuterSquarePen, OuterRect, 1.0F, 360.0F)

    ' create inner square
    InnerSquarePen = New Pen(InnerSquarePen_Color, InnerSquarePen_Width)
    Dim sweepAngle As Short = getSweepAngleFromGoalsPercent()
    Gclock.DrawArc(InnerSquarePen, OuterRect, -90.0F, sweepAngle)
End Sub
```

As you also might've seen I am constantly redeclaring a new `Gclock` variable in the `Paint` event. This is because the `Graphics` instance used to draw your panel with might change, so you shouldn't store it any longer than the time the `Paint` event lasts (so I highly recommend you remove the declaration in the top of your class).

Comment: thank you. you wrote: "Graphics class will not store any information about what you draw, so when your panel is redrawn everything you previously drew will be gone unless you draw it again". so i tryed to pass the clockPannel object to Create() method as parameter after it was created and its also works. now i need to decide if i should use the paint Event VS passing existing object to Graphics... tnx again.

Comment: @jonathana : You really should use the Paint event as that is the way you're supposed to draw controls. As LarsTech already pointed out one shouldn't use `CreateGraphics()`.

Comment: @jonathana : Good. The thing is, if you were to call `Refresh()` on your panel or doing something that causes redraw, your "passing existing object to Graphics" method would yet again not work because as I said: what you draw is not preserved the next time your control is redrawn. -- Good luck with your project!